# Is it possible to manage Verizon Premium CDN 's rules engine during deployment from Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cdn

I have an angular application that is hosted in an Azure storage account with static website enabled.  I'd like to use one of Azure's CDN options.  I see that I can force HTTPS using the Verizon Premium offering's rules engine.  The problem is that I cannot figure out how to manage the rules other than through the portal.

Any idea if this can be accomplished through an API or Powershell?

I suppose I could even take a step back and ask if there is a better way to force this redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a method to manage the rules other than through the portal, also the rules engine is offered by 3rd party CDN provider.

Take a step back, you could select to use [Azure Application Gateway with HTTP to HTTPS redirection.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-http-to-https-portal) A routing rule is used to redirect HTTP traffic to the HTTPS port in your application gateway. Some things will look like these followings:

1. Create a CNAME record to map your custom DNS address to your Application Gateway If you want to access it via a custom domain.
2. Target the **primary endpoint** value of the static website in the storage account page as the backend of App Gw. (e.g. webstoragetest.z19.web.core.windows.net)
3. You could create a self-signed certificate for test purpose or get a free cert from https://letsencrypt.org/. Under Listener configuration, select **HTTPS**, then select **Select a file** and upload your .pfx file.
4. Host header overrides in **HTTP settings**. From HTTP-settings configuration, go to **Host name** property and provide storage account **primary endpoint** value.
5. Suggest not enabling Azure Storage Virtual Network and Firewall Rules at the first time to avoid some network access restriction.

You could get more details from this blog: **[Static Website hosting in Azure Storage with Custom Domain and SSL support using Azure Application Gateway](https://medium.com/@emin.askerov/static-website-hosting-in-azure-storage-with-custom-domain-and-ssl-support-using-azure-application-b17f95c6764c)**

Comment: Brilliant!  I have been wanting to use the application gateway to take advantage of the security features.  Just haven't had the time.  Thank you, I will be following your advice!